# Unable to load PHP session info

Tags: php, session, authentication

I am trying to make a log-in system in PHP. Ive got all the database stuff working, but trying to save and load the session, so the user is logged in as they navigate my site is not working. I set the session info like so:

```
session_start();
...database code
if($count==1){
//log in info correct, save to session and redirect back.
$_SESSION['username'] =$username;
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true";

header("location:../index.php");
}
```

Then, back on the index page.

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
  echo "You must be logged in!";    
  }else{
  echo "You are logged in"; 
  }
?>
```

This code all happens at the top of the page, before any html. Even after logging in, it says "You Must be Logged In" 
Any help would be great :) Thanks

Comment: Have you try a var_dump($_SESSION) to see the content?

The you shouldn't use $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true" but $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE

Comment: Does `$count` actually equal 1?

Comment: the var dump returns "array(0) { }"

                                                                     Yeah, it equals 1, cause if it doesnt, I redirect to a login failed page.

Comment: If $_SESSION returns zero means, it is not set, so first check your database code and $count value whether it is 1 or not.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xj7Ehn86 - I redirect to ../index.php so the session code must be running

Comment: Use session_start(); inside if condition... and use $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1; then check other page session with if else condition...

Comment: Moving the session_start() inside the if statement does not fix it, nor does setting loggedin to 1 instead of true

Comment: var_dump your Session in the login page itself before redirect to see if your SESSION is working or not.

Comment: var_dump on the loggin page works, and outputs array(2) { ["loggedin"]=> string(4) "true" ["username"]=> string(4) "Jack" }

Comment: Did u try to use the var_dump on SESSION , on the home page , because it seems to be very odd why it is not going to work ?

Comment: On the homepage, after header redirecting back, the session is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, seems to work find. Just declare the variable before the if($count ... and change isset to empty.

```
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "";

        if($count == 1)
        {
            /*same thing */
        }


        if(!empty($_SESSION['loggedin']))
        {
            echo "You are logged in";  
        }else
        {
            echo "You must be logged in!";   
        }
```

Also imo, I think it will be better to put the header where the echo is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking a session use empty() and not isset(). isset() returns true if the array is created, not if the key matches.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
  //do the checks to verify the person

} else {
  //they aren't logged in

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Is your cookies disabled?  If it is, please enable and check.

Your code just looks fine and SESSION should work like a breeze if *$count* really equals 1.

If this is not the case, check your phpinfo which should look like this:

```
                 session
Session Support                 enabled
Registered save handlers            files user mm sqlite
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx
```

Comment: Nope, cookies are enabled in my browser, so that shouldnt be the problem

Comment: isset($_SESSION['anything']) will return true because you started the session.